# Buffering IAsyncEnumerable in producer/consumer scenario

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, producer-consumer, iasyncenumerable

I Have a scenario in which I am reading some data from a database. This data is returned in the form of `IAsyncEnumerable<MyData>`. After reading the data I want to send it to a consumer. This consumer is asynchronous. Right now my code looks something like this:

```cs
// C#
IAsyncEnumerable<MyData> enumerable = this.dataSource.Read(query);

await foreach (var data in enumerable) 
{
    await this.consumer.Write(data);
}
```

My problem with this is that while I am enumerating the database, I am holding a lock on the data. I don't want to hold this lock for longer than I need to.

In the event that the consumer is consuming data slower than the producer is producing it, is there any way I can eagerly read from the datasource without just calling `ToList` or `ToListAsync`. I want to avoid reading all the data into memory at once, which would cause the opposite problem if now the producer is slower than the consumer. It is ok if the lock on the database is not as short as possible, I want a configurable tradeoff between how much data is in memory at once, and how long we keep the enumeration running.

My thought is that there would be some way to use a queue or channel-like datastructure to act as a buffer between the producer and consumer.

In Golang I would do something like this:

```golang
// go
queue := make(chan MyData, BUFFER_SIZE)
go dataSource.Read(query, queue)

// Read sends data on the channel, closes it when done

for data := range queue {
    consumer.Write(data)
}
```

Is there any way to get similar behavior in C#?

Comment: "any way I can eagerly read from the datasource without just calling ToList" well, it sounds like you need to pull all the results into memory, which can be done with......

Comment: Let me clarify, I don't want read the whole thing into memory at once, this would have the opposite problem if now the producer was slower than the consumer.

Comment: I don't know go, so I'm asking this: what happens in your go code if the producer is slower? Wouldn't the queue be quickly emptied and the loop would end before the producer has produced everything? The consumer would end up not consume everything.

Comment: You can use BlockingCollection with ConcurrentQueue and max size set (analog of buffer size you have in go). Producer will put items there, blocking if max size is reached, and consumer will, well, consume, blocking if queue is empty (waiting for the next item). Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Sweeper, the loop will block and wait for a new item until the producer closes the queue.

Comment: You will just need to offload putting items into that blocking collection to run in parallel and not sequential like now (like you do with "go" in go example).

Comment: Are you in control of the `this.dataSource.Read` implementation, or it's implemented by Microsoft or a third party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a more robust implementation of the `ConsumeBuffered` extension method in [Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199747/11178549)'s answer. This one uses a [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) as buffer, instead of a `BlockingCollection<T>`. The advantage is that the enumeration of the two sequences, the source and the buffered, does not block one thread each. Care has been taken to complete the enumeration of the source sequence, in case the enumeration of the buffered sequence is abandoned prematurely by the consumer downstream.

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ConsumeBuffered<T>(
    this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source, int capacity,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    Channel<T> channel = Channel.CreateBounded<T>(new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity)
    {
        SingleWriter = true,
        SingleReader = true,
    });
    using CancellationTokenSource completionCts = new();

    Task producer = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            await foreach (T item in source.WithCancellation(completionCts.Token)
                .ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (ChannelClosedException) { } // Ignore
        finally { channel.Writer.TryComplete(); }
    });

    try
    {
        await foreach (T item in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            yield return item;
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        await producer.ConfigureAwait(false); // Propagate possible source error
    }
    finally
    {
        // Prevent fire-and-forget in case the enumeration is abandoned
        if (!producer.IsCompleted)
        {
            completionCts.Cancel();
            channel.Writer.TryComplete();
            await Task.WhenAny(producer).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the `SingleWriter` and `SingleReader` options of the bounded channel is a bit academic, and could be omitted. Currently (.NET 6) there is only one bounded `Channel<T>` implementation in the [System.Threading.Channels](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels) library, regardless of the supplied options. [This implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/54b12a83a329dbc4079c254dc7071cb528e1f2f1/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/BoundedChannel.cs) is based on a `Deque<T>` (internal .NET type similar with a `Queue<T>`) synchronized with a `lock`.

The channel is enumerated inside a `try`/`finally` block, because C# iterators execute the `finally` blocks as part of the `Dispose`/`DisposeAsync` method of the autogenerated `IEnumerator<T>`/`IAsyncEnumerator<T>`, when the enumeration is abandoned.

**Note:** In case the external `CancellationToken` is canceled, the cancellation is propagated as an `OperationCanceledException`, and all the buffered items are lost. In a producer-consumer scenario with multiple producers and consumers, this might be a problem. It is advised that the `CancellationToken` is used only for the purpose of destroying the entire processing pipeline, not for parts of it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to yield within a try-catch block... is that limited to just certain versions of C#?

Comment: @Rafael if I remember correctly you can't `yield` from a `try` block that has a `catch` block. But `try`+`finally` is OK (without `catch`).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Evk for pointing me towards the `BlockingCollection<T>`, this is the solution I came up with. It allows me to eagerly produce from an `IAsyncEnumerable` even if the consumer can't keep up. It may also be possible to come up with a similar solution using `System.Threading.Channels` to mimic the Go example.

```cs
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ConsumeBuffered<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> enumerable, int? maxBuffer = null)
    where T: class
{
    using (BlockingCollection<T> queue = maxBuffer == null ? new BlockingCollection<T>() : new BlockingCollection<T>(maxBuffer.Value))
    {
        Task producer = Task.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                await foreach (T item in enumerable.ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    queue.Add(item);
                }

                queue.CompleteAdding();
            });

        while (true)
        {
            T next;
            try
            {
                next = queue.Take();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException _)
            {
                // thrown when we try to Take after last item
                break;
            }

            yield return next;
        }

        // this might not be needed, task must be done 
        // if we exited the loop
        await producer.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Probably needs some polishing and testing for edge cases, but seems to work in UT

Comment: How does this help at solving your problem? If you set the `maxBuffer`, the `queue.Add` will block when the `BlockingCollection<T>` is full, so the `await foreach` will get blocked, keeping the database locked, which is what you want to avoid. If you don't set the `maxBuffer`, the `await foreach` will run at max speed and will store all the data inside the `BlockingCollection<T>`, which is a less efficient storage than a `List<T>`, which is also something that you want to avoid. One way or another you end up in an undesirable situation.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias for my scenario I expect the consumer to be only slightly slower than the producer. You are correct that in the worst case, the unbounded queue will just fill up with the entire dataset, but as long as the consumer is able to consume a few elements faster than the producer can produce the entire dataset, we still prevent the queue containing the dataset whole at any given point. You make a very good point though, I will consider this further.

Comment: Best case scenario for your solution is that the database will get locked for half the time, and then half the data will get buffered. So it's a compromise between locking the database until all the data are consumed, and buffering all the data in memory. The question gives no clue that such compromise is satisfactory. To make this answer a valid answer for your question, you should edit the question and describe the kind of compromise that you are looking for.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, I will edit the question to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `while (true) bext = queue.Take();` it's simpler to do `foreach (var next in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())`. Also this solution will result in a memory leak in case the enumeration of the resulting `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is abandoned prematurely (after either a `break` or an exception), because the `Task producer` will never get completed, and the database will remain locked until the whole process terminates.